# In Azure, how to change the authentication of the server?

Tags: azure

When spinning up a linux virtual machine, I have chosen the authentication type as password. Now I want to change to ssh. How to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you want to change password or change authentication type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Azure portal to reset password, like this:

[image]

If you want to change authentication type, you can follow this steps:
1. Create an SSH key pair

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
```

2. rename `id_rsa.put` to `authorized_keys`

```
mv /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

3.Copy `id_rsa` to your local, then you can use this key to SSH it.

Comment: How to setup the private key in the server? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: After you run `ssh-keygen`, you can find two files in `~/.ssh`,

Comment: Thanks It works. So the id_rsa has the private key rite? (And the private key is in our local system)

Comment: @Minisha Yes, `id_rsa` is the private key, you can use this key to ssh this VM.